# Java UDP message exchange works over localhost but not Internet?

Tags: java, udp, ip, localhost, ports

Client A

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class ClientA 
    {
    final private static int PORT = 5005; // arbitrarily assigned port to use

public static void main(String args[]) throws 
IOException
{
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT); // create new connection on that port
    while (true) 
    {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[256]; // data buffer
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length); // new packet containing buffer

        socket.receive(packet);  // look for packet

        String clientBMsg = new String(packet.getData()); // get data from received packet
        InetAddress address = packet.getAddress(); // get address of received packet

        System.out.println("ClientB at " + address + " says " + clientBMsg);

        buffer = null;
        String msgString = "I'm ClientA, vegetables are fun";
        buffer = msgString.getBytes(); // put String in buffer


        int port = packet.getPort(); // get port of received packet
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, port); // create new packet with this data
        socket.send(packet); // send packet back containing new buffer!
        System.out.println("Message Sent");
        socket.close();
       }
}
    }
```

Client B

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;


    public class ClientB 
    {
final private static int PORT = 5005; // arbitrarily assigned port - same as server

public static void main(String args[]) throws 
    IOException {
        // if (args.length == 0) { // requires host
            // System.err.println
                // ("Please specify host");
            // System.exit(-1);
        // }
        // String host = args[0]; // user defined host
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(); // open new socket

        String host = "localhost";//"86.0.164.207";
        byte message[] = new byte[256]; // empty message
        String msgString = "Hello, I'm client B and I like trees";
        message = msgString.getBytes(); // put String in buffer

        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host); // determines address
        System.out.println("Sending to: " + address); // tells user it's doing something
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, address, PORT); // create packet to send

        socket.send(packet); // send packet
        System.out.println("Message Sent");

        message = new byte[256];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
        socket.receive(packet); // wait for response
        String clientAreply = new String(packet.getData());
        System.out.println("ClientA at " + host + " says " + clientAreply);
        socket.close();

        }
      }
```

I don't understand why this works over localhost but when I put my IP address in, it just sends the message and nothing is received.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thank you!

Comment: are you behind a firewall and/or NAT by any chance?

Comment: I ensured that the ports were forwarded on my router?

Comment: Please, describe your network setup, it's not clear where you run those two processes.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `DatagramSocket`'s `bind` method to bind it to your internet interface, otherwise it only listens on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. Like this:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("your.ip.add.ress"),5005);
```

In case you are behind your router then your should listen on the local IP address given to you by the router and use port forwarding to this address in your router settings.

Comment: Sorry, should this be for client A or B?

Comment: Both client should have their ip otherwise they will not be able to see eachother over the internet. Localhost and 127.0.0.1 should only apply when the are running on the same machine.

Comment: When I run that I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: Please, describe your network setup. You've mentioned some router you've used to forward ports. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ubuntu virtual machine on Win7 connected wirelessly to a router, have forwarded the ports I'm using on the router, and using my public IP address.

Comment: Are you running both clients on that one ubuntu VM?

Comment: Yes, I don't have access to anything else at the moment. But I get the exception saying I cannot assign to requested address when I run just one client

Comment: Check your VM's address, it could have its own local address assigned by your VM host application. Use unix `ifconfig` command to list interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using [Socket Test](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/) tool with TCP and UDP Sockets:

- http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/

I used it to trouble shoot issues with a 2-way socket program.  You can end-to-end test your link with two SocketTest programs and the compare results, etc.  Very useful.